# Broadcasting 10k SSIDs

Tags: wifi

How hard would it be, and or is it possible, to configure a router or PC to broadcast ten thousand SSIDs. If it is possible what repercussions would it have? Would this be a form of DOSing or is there some mitigation that would prevent it?

It's surely possible to broadcast a few as most routers can setup multiple SSIDs. Is it likely many devices seeing all the SSIDs would crash? I'd guess many devices have a limited amount of memory reserved for looking at ids.

If you used ids that started with 00000 so they show up near the beginning of most sorted lists would it make it nearly impossible to select the legitimate WiFi SSIDs at the bottom of the list?

Comment: Most devices I've seen sort SSIDs in terms of strength, so the strongest ones would be at the top, rather than those that were named alphabetically first.

Comment: Give this tool a try: [MDK3](http://tools.kali.org/wireless-attacks/mdk3) it does what you want, you give it a list of SSIDs and it broadcasts all of them.

Comment: I see 3 downvotes, but I don't see any reason why this is downvoted (I'm not saying that there isn't any, I just don't see it in the comments).